# How to compute the inverse of $I + A$, where $A$ is skew-symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

As we all know that if $A$ is Real skew Symmetric Matrix, then $I-A$ is Non singular. 
But if we really want to compute that inverse, I wonder if there is a closed form solution.

Comment: Of course: Cramer's Rule says $(I+A)^{-1} = \text{Adj}(I+A)/\det(I+A)$.

Comment: Or is that not "closed" enough for you?

Comment: If we know the eigenvalues of $A$ (or of the symmetric matrix $A^2$) then we can use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to compute the inverse